# Val doesn't get the value of span

Tags: jquery

I need to get some information with jquery and I am stuck. I am doing something wrong.
This is the structure of html. These demands_divs are dynamically created before so there are many of them:

```
<div class="demands_div">
    <div class="demands_img_div">
        <img class="demands_img" alt="Student Logo" src="/images/students.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div><b>Description:</b><span class="introduction">In pariatur In arch</span> </div>
    <div><b>Preference:</b><span class="preference">Face to Face</span></div>
    <div><b>For Whom:</b><span class="who">For Other</span></div>
    <div><b>E-mail:</b><span class="email">muzicaxube@mailinator.com</span> </div>
    <div><b>Telephone:</b><span class="telephone">+1 (503) 912-6742</span></div>
    <div><b>Date:</b><span class="date">2022-03-01 19:43:40</span></div>
    <button type="submit" name="demand_submit" value="delete" class="demand_submit">Bu Kaydı Silin</button>
</div>
```

And this is my attempt to get information from each span when the button is clicked. By the way on click is working I've tested so the problem must be in the selection.

```
  $(".demand_submit").on("click", function(){           
 introduction = $(this).parent().find(".introduction").val();
 preference = $(this).parent().find(".preference").val();
 who = $(this).parent().find(".who").val();
  email = $(this).parent().find(".email").val();
  telephone = $(this).parent().find(".telephone").val();
   date = $(this).parent().find(".date").val();                     
                        })
```

Comment: You're trying to use `.val()` on `<span>` elements, which do not have a `value` attribute. Did you try `.text()` instead?

Comment: Also, instead of repeating `$(this).parent()` a bunch of times, define it as a variable and use that: `let parentDiv = $(this).closest('.demands_div')`, then `introduction = parentDiv.find('.introduction').text();`, etc.

Comment: @TimLewis Yes and it does work. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TimLewis Yes I am going to do that makes sense.

Comment: Please don't deface you original question. The edit you made removed a lot of important information, and rendered the answer below redundant. If you don't want this question here, you may delete it, but any further attempts to edit it and remove that information may be met with harsher actions.

Comment: @TimLewis I am sorry, you are right. I was trying to make it simple. I am kinda new and getting used to the rules. I do appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries  I understand the thinking, but questions, once answered, should not be edited, unless absolutely necessary. Minor edits, like wording and spacing/formatting are fine, but the edit you made removed all the important information, which is a general no-no. Repeated offences can result in you not being able to ask/edit questions, but that's in severe cases. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to get values, when you should be trying to get the text.
Changing **.val()** to **.text()** should allow you to get the text data.

Comment: It's solved the problem. Thank you very much. I'll mark it as solved in 7 minutes.